# Insert a value in date format dd-mm-yyyy in dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I am creating a dictionary having some values including a date of birth of  a person. But when I run my code, it is giving an error "datetime.datetime has no attribute datetime" . Here is my code:

```
    import re
from datetime import date
import datetime
from datetime import datetime
userDetails=[]
dateOfBith='9-9-1992'
#datetimeparse = datetime.strptime(dateOfBith,'%dd-%mm-%yyyy')
datetimeparse = datetime.datetime.strptime(dateOfBith, '%Y-%m-%d').strftime('%d/%m/%y')
dateparse = datetime(datetimeparse)
accountDetails= {"FirstName": "ajay", "LastName": "kumar","Account Number":"4242342345234","Balance Currency":"Rs","Balance Amount":"5000"}
accountDetails["DateOfBirth"] = dateparse
```

Comment: so did you import datetime? e.g. `import datetime`?

Comment: I don't think your format matches with what you want to parse. Shouldn't it be `%d-%m-%Y` ?

Comment: The 1992th of September, in the year 9 ?

Comment: I have edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

Do your dates always look the same? If not:

## Installation

```
pip3 install python-dateutil
pip3 install pytz
```

## Code

```
import datetime
import dateutil
import dateutil.parser
import pytz

date_in = dateOfBith = '9-9-1992'

try:
    if date_in.count('.') >= 2:
        date_out = dateutil.parser.parse(date_in, dayfirst=True)
    else:
        date_out = dateutil.parser.parse(date_in, dayfirst=False)
        # Additional parameters for parse:
        # dayfirst=True  # In ambiguous dates it is assumed that the day is further forward.
        # default=datetime.datetime(1,1,1,0,0,0)  # Used only piecewise, i.e. if the year is missing, year will be 1, the rest remains!
        # fuzzy=True  # Ignores words before and after the date.
except ValueError as e:
    print(repr(e))

print(date_out.isoformat())  # returns 1992-09-09T00:00:00

timezone_utc = pytz.utc
timezone_berlin = pytz.timezone('Europe/Berlin')  # Put your capital here!

try:
    date_out = timezone_berlin.localize(date_out)
except ValueError as e:
    print(repr(e))

print(date_out.isoformat())  # returns 1992-09-09T00:00:00+02:00

if date_out > timezone_utc.localize(datetime.datetime.utcnow()):
    print('The date is in the future.')
```

Tested with Python 3.4.3 on Ubuntu 14.04.