# Split multiple fields in one columns

Tags: python, file, dataframe

I have the following text,

```
04/20/2009; 04/20/09; 4/20/09; 4/3/09
Mar-20-2009; Mar 20, 2009; March 20, 2009; Mar. 20, 2009; Mar 20 2009;
20 Mar 2009; 20 March 2009; 20 Mar. 2009; 20 March, 2009
Mar 20th, 2009; Mar 21st, 2009; Mar 22nd, 2009
Feb 2009; Sep 2009; Oct 2010
6/2008; 12/2009
2009; 2010
```

My idea is to replace all dates into a single format but I need to set all the dates into a single pd.Series column object.

This is what I am doing so far.

```
with open('dates.txt') as file:
    for row in file:
        doc.append(line)
```

And I would like something like

```
1 0          Mar-20-2009
  1         Mar 20, 2009
  2       March 20, 2009
  3        Mar. 20, 2009
  4          Mar 20 2009
2 0          20 Mar 2009
  1        20 March 2009
  2         20 Mar. 2009
  3       20 March, 2009
3 0       Mar 20th, 2009
  1       Mar 21st, 2009
  2       Mar 22nd, 2009
4 0             Feb 2009
  1             Sep 2009
  2             Oct 2010
```

Comment: Can you post expected output?

Comment: If you want to parse the dates so that they are in the same format, you may use the code I posted the day before yesterday about a similar problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51422379/1707015

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to create a series from that text file do the following

```
with open(file) as f:
    txt = f.read().replace("\n","")
series = pd.Series(txt.split(";"))
```